# Adding drawables to each view in recycleview timeline

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a frame by frame animation app. On the main drawing screen I have a recyclerview timeline at the bottom of the screen for holding each canvas drawing. When the user is finished drawing and wants to create a new frame, the timeline view should be updated to include an image of that specific drawing in the timeline.

I am converting each bitmap to a drawable object, then storing that in a hashmap with the correct position.

The error I am getting is that each view is the first frame the user draws.

[image: drawing screen with timeline at bottom]

this is the method in my main activity

```
//setting up the hashmap of drawable objects
public static Map<Integer, Drawable> drawables = new HashMap<>();

public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

    // this sets the bitmap to the drawing on screen
    this.canvasView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = this.canvasView.getDrawingCache();

    // this is just to reset the adapterPosition so the else statement gets called in onBindViewHolder
    adapterPosition = position;

   // convert bitmap to drawable then places into right position in hashmap
    myDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    drawables.put(this.pos,myDrawable); 

    // change the position value to the position of the recyclerview item clicked
    this.pos = position

    //call onBindViewHolder to update the recylerview
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this is my onBindViewHolder method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Integer res = mFrames.get(position);

    //if statement only happens on first frame so set the image as default image
    if (adapterPosition == 20) {
        holder.myView.setBackgroundResource(res);
    }
    else{
        //get the drawable for the each position of the recyclerview using hashmap
        holder.myView.setBackground(drawables.get(position));
    }
```

The view should be getting a different image for each position in the hashmap drawables when onBindView is called, but its returning the image in the first position every time

Answer (score 0):

Here's that I see in your code:

1. Your current approach of setting the `adapterPosition` in `onItemClick()` is wrong. You should only use the `position` provided in `onBindViewHolder()`.
2. The `drawables` map should **not** be static.

These might not fix your problem immediately but are steps in the right direction. Showing more code would also help, e.g. how are frames added to `mFrames`, who calls `onItemClick()`, etc.